# Null Pointer Exception on first element add to my Generic ChunkList

Tags: java

So I have a null pointer exception when run. I am supposed to create a generic class that implements a list with chunks of arrays added as needed. Each time I add an element it is to check if there is space in the tail chunk array and if so add the element. Else it needs to add a chunk, adjust the pointers and add the element. My problem so far is that when I go to add the first element it is throwing a null pointer exception. I believe I have instantiated and object and assigned it where needed. If anyone has any insight please feel free to let me know what I am doing wrong or maybe its right in front of my face.

"myChunk.chunk_.add(element);////////////error"    is where I am getting the error.

```
package ChunkList;


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class chunkList<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        chunkList<Integer> myList=new chunkList<Integer>();

        for(int i=1; i<24; i++)
        {
            myList.add(i);//////////////////////////////////
            System.out.println("Adding number: "+ i);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        myList.display();


    }


    private chunk head;//changed T to chunk
    private chunk tail;//changed T to chunk
    private int array_size=8;
    private int list_size;

    public chunkList()//Default Constructor
    {
        head=null;
        tail=null;
        list_size=0;
    }

    //public chunkList(chunkList copy){}// a copy constructor.... don't think I need.

    class chunk//  added <T>
    {
        //T[] chunk_arr  = new T[array_size];// illegal operation
        //ArrayList<T> chunk_ = new ArrayList<T>(array_size);
        ArrayList<T> chunk_; 

        private int chunk_size; //may need to change to public
        chunk nextChunk;//changed T to chunk
        chunk prevChunk;//changed T to chunk

        public chunk()//default constructor
        {
            chunk_ = new ArrayList<T>(array_size);
            chunk_size=0;
            nextChunk=null;
            prevChunk=null;
        }
    }

    public void add(T element)
    {
        if(this.tail==null)//empty chunk list
        {
            chunk myChunk=new chunk();//instantiate

            //myChunk.prevChunk=null;//changed from head to null
            //myChunk.nextChunk=null;//changed from tail to null
            head=myChunk;
            tail=myChunk;
            //head.nextChunk=null;
            //head.prevChunk=null;

            myChunk.chunk_.add(element);////////////error
            list_size++;
            myChunk.chunk_size=1;
        }
        else if (this.tail.chunk_size<array_size)//adds the element to the last chunk in list
        {
            this.tail.chunk_.add(element);//add element

            list_size++;
            this.tail.chunk_size++;//increase individual chunk array size
        }
        else// create new chunk, relink chunks, add element
        {
                        chunk myChunk=new chunk();

        myChunk.chunk_size=1;   
        list_size++;
        myChunk.chunk_.add(element);

        tail.nextChunk=myChunk;
        myChunk.prevChunk=tail;
        tail=myChunk;
        }}

     public int size()
         {return list_size;}

     public void display()
     {
         chunk my_chunk=head;

         if(my_chunk==null)
         {
             System.out.print("Empty Chunk List");
             return;
         }

         for(int i=0;i<list_size;  )
         {
             for(int j=0; j<my_chunk.chunk_size;  j++)
             {
                 System.out.println(my_chunk.chunk_.get(j));
                 i++;
             }
             if(my_chunk.nextChunk!=null)
             my_chunk=my_chunk.nextChunk;
         }
     }


}
```

So thanks Olivier Jacot-Descombes , I fixed one problem with the code and it now adds the first chunk BUT it is throwing NPE when it tries to create the next chunk. I will look at it and be back if i need more help. Thanks All.

P.S. The add method on this was incorrectly linked together in the last else statement.

Comment: Another effective technique is to explain your code to someone else.  This will often cause you to explain the bug to yourself.  Sometimes it takes no more than a few sentences, followed by an embarrassed "Never mind, I see what's wrong.  Sorry to bother you."  This works remarkably well; you can even use non-programmers as listeners.  One university computer center kept a teddy bear near the help desk.  Students with mysterious bugs were required to explain them to the bear before they could speak to a human counselor.  ~Brian Kernighan and Rob Pike, about debugging

Comment: 1. You code is really messy. Please review http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf. 2. The NPE is thrown because you do not instantiate the `ArrayList<T> chunk_`. PLace a breakpoint at theis line `myChunk.chunk_.add(element)` and review carefully what is going on in side your default c'tor of the chunk<T> class.

Comment: When ever I call "chunk myChunk=new chunk();//instantiate" does that not then call the default constructor for the chunk class and within that constructor it instantiates the "ArrayList<T>(array_size)"?

Comment: Having the methods of `chunkList` operate on the (what should be private) members of `chunk` is not a good design. Moving the chunk-based logic to the `chunk` class itself would clean up the code considerably and possibly lead to finding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very strange

- There is a `public static void main(String[] args)` inside the class `chunkList<T>`. This makes no sense.
- You declare a `chunkList<Integer>` instead of `chunkList<int>`.
- You re-declare a `chunk<T> head` and `chunk<T> tail` in the constructor. The code should simply be `head = null;` without `chunk<T>`.
- In the constructor of `chunk` you do the same thing again with `ArrayList<T> chunk_ = ...`.

I could tell more things; however, I think that you should start by fixing these things to begin with.

Comment: Having the main inside the chunkList<T> is not the problem. It makes it easer to trythings in main. I will move it to a seperate .java when done. When I delcare chunkList<Integer> instead of <int> that is because from what I know that you cant put a premitive into a generic type. The chunk<T> head , chunk<T> tail was done after I had problems with the null pointer exception. Might not of been the right fix but I do not think its wrong .

Comment: It is confusing to have a local `head` and `tail` as well as `head` and `tail` members. These are four different variables!

Comment: the only head and tail I see are for the generic chunkList class. Then the chunk class has prevChunk and nextChunk. I don't understand what head and tail you are calling "local" and which ones you are calling "members". Every where that I am using them is it not the same ones that are for that object.  And i changed the code up to how I had it before I added all the <T>

Comment: Because you have a type (chunk) in front of `head` in the constructor, `chunk head=null;` declares a new variable that exists only inside of the constructor! If you want to initialize the `head` declared in the class you must drop the type: `head=null;`. Like you have done with `list_size=0;` already. `int list_size=0;` would be wrong.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You can't declare `chunkList<int>`, generics don't work with primitive types. Having a `main()` method in a class for testing purposes is OK, what makes you think it's a problem? However, you are right about the re-declarations of variables. Actually, they cause `chunk.chunk_` to not be initialized and the NPE to be thrown as a result later on.

Comment: ok, i fixed that. It was not the error I was getting but I understand what you meant that it was declaring a local varible whos scope was just the constructor. With that in mind let me look through my code some more.

Comment: You are right, of cause (I'm a C# guy). There are several of these re-declarations.

Answer (score 0):

**NAMING STANDARDS PLEASE!**

You will immediately benefit from adhering to industry naming standards, because your code will be more easily read by others when you ask for their help. Also, you'll be able to read other's code more easily too.

In java, convention is that:

- all names are [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)
- all names start with a lowercase letter, except class names start with a capital letter
- constants are all-capitals with underscore separation (eg `MY_CONSTANT`)
- tend not to abbreviate names
- don't use [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)

To apply this to your code, make the following changes:

- Rename `chunkList` to `ChunkList`
- Rename `array_size` to `arraySize`
- Rename `my_chunk` to `myChunk`
- Rename `chunk_ to`chunk`

Now, to answer your question, just use a `java.util.LinkedList` and stop trying to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Yeah... tell this to the proffesor that is "teaching" me java